# Url Decoding not working on Azure Web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, umbraco, azure-web-app-service, urldecode

I seem to be having an issue with Url's being decoded on the stage site incorrectly. I have been looking around online but I can't seem to find anything on how to switch what decoding method is used by default. I can tell that the stage site is using Windows-1252 to decode urls, example below:

Stage site (Wrong)

```
de-de/people/%C3%A1ine-hurley/ -> de-de/people/Ã¡ine-hurley
```

Dev site (Correct)

```
de-de/people/%C3%A1ine-hurley/ -> de-de/berater/áine-hurley
```

The dev an live site are both rendering the correct url, which is being decoded using UTF-8. for a comparasion of decoding characters you can visit this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

I am at a loss really, Both stage and live are setup in Azure web apps and from what I can see have the same settings (however I have a feeling it is probably a server setting somewhere).

If anyone could give me more information on how this works or if its possible to change decoding settings on a server that would be much appreciated. If any more information is needed, I am happy to provide it. I was just unsure of what information would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, I noticed the stage site was actually issuing 301 permanent redirects to a URL that had first been decoded using windows-1252 then re-encoded as UTF-8 (this is very peculiar, as I can't find anywhere in code that would have done this, nor could I find anything in the rewrite rules).

However this was resolved by adding in a permanent canonical redirect to resolve the staging site without www. and force it to stage.sitename.come. Example canonical below:

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true" >
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\." negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

If someone knows why this would resolve the issue, would love to know :). Hope this helps someone else if they have this problem.